# How to transcode video stream by changing only the resolution?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to transcode video stream using ffmpeg tool and change only the video stream resolution, i.e. the video and audio parameters should remain the same.

According to the man page of the ffmpeg the following command line should provide the desired result:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -s WxH output.avi
```

The Video codec of the input stream is compatible with avi container.

The actual result is that the resolution remains unchanged and it seems that the stream is just repacked in avi container.

The resolution of the output stream is changed successfully without `-vcodec copy` option, but the video codec is changed:  h264 (Constrained Baseline) - > mpeg4 (Simple Profile).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `copy` a video stream, you cannot change any of its paramters, since… well, you're copying it. `ffmpeg` won't touch it in any way, so it can't change the dimensions, frame rate, et cetera.

Also, `ffmpeg` always chooses a default video codec if you don't specify one. For AVI files, that's `mpeg4`.

If you want H.264 video, choose `-c:v libx264` instead (or `-vcodec libx264` which is the same). If you need to keep the original profile, use `-profile:v baseline`.

Two things:

- When you change the size, you will recode the video. This lowers the quality and might considerably harm the video. To compensate for this, you might need to set a higher quality level. You do this by [setting the Constant Rate Factor](http://slhck.info/crf.html) to anything below the default of 23, e.g. with `-crf 20`. Experiment and see how your video looks like. If you have the time, add the `-preset slow` (or `slower`, `veryslow`), which will give you better compression.
- Not that it matters in your case, since your input uses the Constrained Baseline profile, but note that H.264 in AVI is not properly supported, at least when using B pictures. Baseline doesn't support B pictures though, so you should be fine. It could happen that file can't be played back on some devices or players if you use the Main profile or anything above. I would rather mux it into an MP4 or MKV container, especially if your input file is MP4 anyway.

Comment: OK I understood the point. 
But the thing is that I want to transcode the video stream in a way, that the difference of the input and output is only the resolution.
I.e. is it possible to get the presets of the encoder of the input file, transcode it using that preset and changing only the resolution?

Comment: Well, you *have* to transcode it. You cannot change "just" the resolution of a video stream. You will have to decode, scale, and then re-encode it, which `-c:v libx264` does for you. The remainder like frame rate, pixel aspect ratio, etc. will stay the same. If you need the Baseline profile you will have to explicitly specify that though, I guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick responses.

Comment: One parameter that can still be changed with `-vcodec copy` is aspect. `-aspect` can be used with `-vcodec copy` to change aspect ratio at the container level: [make -aspect work with -vcodec copy](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=b1cc12d0e3aa9f800de1cd6ffa6a2c54e78b4e5d).